# Is there any Mac OS software really supporting Windows RemoteApp?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is there any Mac OS software that supports properly Windows Terminal Server RemoteApp?  By Properly I mean with an experience comparable to Windows Remote Desktop, that is, the Remote App Window is resizeable, etc, as if it was just another application.

Most tools (RDC for Mac, CoRD) seem to simply open a desktop for the application, but it does not have a truly windowed behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not even the official Microsoft RDP Client for OS X supports this; in fact that product still cannot do Terminal Services Gateway connections that were introduced with Windows Server 2008

*But the answer to your question is, yes there is at least one client that promotes full RemoteFX implemetation in their OS X client (and incidentally also TSG), and that's [iTap Mobile RDP](http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp).  It is a commercial program however there is a trial version available from that page.  **Update: it looks like iTap don't fully support RemoteApp***

The only other client I can find is one by Thinomenon.  [Their free client](http://www.thinomenon.com/products/RemoteDesktopClient/osx.aspx#details) supports all versions of the RDP protocol up to 7 (RemoteApp requires 6.1 or greater)

```
Enjoy latest RDP features, including application publishing (RemoteApp or RAIL), even if your platform is not supported by Microsoft.

Product Features:
 - RDP 4.0, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 6.0, 6.1 and 7 -compatible,
 - Copy and Paste via clipboard,
 - Encryption for communication security,
 - Local audio.
```

Comment: I just tried iTap Mobile RDP and I cannot make it work as a resizeable window.  If I open the same .rdp file I use on Windows, it lauches full scheen, and if I switch to non-fullsecreen mode, there is not a seemless resizing connection among the Windows application window frame and the Mac window frame.  MOreover, if I launch a Windows Explorer from the Windows application, its the Explorer window is not a Mac Window by itself, but instead is confined within the application's window.  Is there any iTap Mobile RDP setting that I am missing?

Comment: is this just a standard RDP file for full desktop connection, or has it been modified and conffiured for the RemoteApp?

Comment: updated my answer, unfortunately never used the product from Thinomenon but as far as I can see, it's the only client of OSX that supports 6.1 and above.

Comment: I was simply using the same RDP file that I was using for Windows (the one provided by our IT department). The Thinomenon product does work well (with regards to the windowing experience).

Answer (score 2):

Another RDP client for Mac is [Ericom Blaze](http://www.ericom.com/ericom_blaze.asp?URL_ID=708).  Blaze supports application publishing.  It also accelerates RDP, which can be especially useful if you are connecting to graphics files like PDFs or Flash movies.

Please note that I work for Ericom

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the authors of iTap mobile RDP. Our next version (1.2) will support Remote App and also fetching the published applications feeds from remote app manager.

If you are interested in getting a beta version, please drop us a note at support@itap-mobile.com

-Peter

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Microsoft has released [an Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) client](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114105311/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2013/10/21/microsoft-remote-desktop-apps-for-ios-mac-os-x-and-android-available-for-download.aspx) with full-support of RDP sessions including [RemoteApps](https://web.archive.org/web/20150403005117/https://www.remoteapp.windowsazure.com/).

The newest version does not support RemoteApp that you host yourself. It only supports Azure RemoteApp (preview).

Answer (score 0):

Thinomenon Remote Desktop Client is working well for us.

Answer (score 0):

check Thinomenon Remote Desktop work fine remoteapps WS2008 in mac Mountain Lion

http://www.thinomenon.com/downloads/thinrdc-0.2.8.rar

Answer (score 0):

I can't say when Microsoft Remote Desktop for OSx/Mac OS started working with RemoteApp. But, as of March 2018, it does.